# How to get an component height to trigger Headroom in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, headroom.js

This is my first time dealing with Gatsby and React, so I might be using the wrong approach on this matter. Anyway, this is what is going on.

From the gatsby-starter-hello-world, I'm building this site that will be composed of a front page with a Hero on the top, holding the intro information. Right bellow, I'm intending to insert some content (I'm not sure about what yet), with this `<Header />` appearing on scroll. For that part, I'm intending on use Headroom.js, which already works in the site. 
The thing is I need it to be triggered only after the bottom of the Hero component touches the top of the viewport. And this will happen only in desktop and laptops. On mobile I intend to make it a fixed navbar.

Anyway, right now, this is what I have for a Layout.js

```js
import React from "react"

import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"

import Hero from "./index/hero"
import Header from "./header"
import Headroom from "react-headroom"

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query SiteTitleQuery {
      site {
        siteMetadata {
          title
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  function() getHeroSize {
    var heroHeight = Hero.clientHeight;
  }


  return (
    <>
      <Hero siteTitle={data.site.siteMetadata.title} ref="inner" />
      <div className={"container mx-auto"}>

      <Headroom pinStart={heroHeight}>
      <Header siteTitle={data.site.siteMetadata.title} />
      </Headroom>


        <div
          //style={{
          //  margin: `0 auto`,
          //  maxWidth: 960,
          //  padding: `0px 1.0875rem 1.45rem`,
          //  paddingTop: 0,
          //}}

        >
          <main>{children}</main>
          <footer>
            © {new Date().getFullYear()}, Construído com
            {` `}
            <a href="https://www.gatsbyjs.org">Gatsby</a>
          </footer>
        </div>
      </div>

    </>
  )
}

Layout.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
}

export default Layout
```

The function getHeroSize above is more like an intention display of what I'm thinking. It doesn't really work.

I'm using Tailwind CSS and sourcing some content from Trello using gatsby-source-trello. Not yet sure how to make this Layout.js, but this is what I've got from some testing that worked pretty good, so far. I understand that there'll be some work to do within gatsby-node.js, but I believe this header will be there in any other page I create, so.

Any thoughts, suggestions or links to documentation would be really appreaciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Hero` component would need to use [`forwardRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) to pass the `ref` to the nearest React element:

```
const Hero = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => 
  <div ref={ref}>
    {props.title}
  </div>
```

Then you'll need to create a ref in `Layout` and pass that to `Hero`:

```
import React, { useRef } from "react"

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  const heroRef = useRef()
  // ...
  return (
    <>
      <Hero title={data.site.siteMetadata.title} ref={heroRef} />
      {/* ... */}
    </>
  )
}
```

Finally, you'll want to use a hook to measure the actual height of the `heroRef.current` element. Here's one I use:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import debounce from "lodash/debounce"

export default (ref, ttl = 100) => {
  const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!ref.current) return

    const measure = debounce(() => {
      if (ref.current) {
        setDimensions(ref.current.getBoundingClientRect())
      }
    }, ttl)

    measure()
    window.addEventListener("resize", measure)

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", measure)
    }
  }, [ref, ttl])

  return dimensions
}
```

And here's how you might add that to `Layout`:

```
import useElementDimensions from "hooks/useElementDimensions"

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  const heroRef = useRef()
  const heroDims = useElementDimensions(heroRef) || { top: 0, height: 0 }
  const heroBottom = heroDims.top + heroDims.height

  return (
    <Headroom pinStart={heroBottom}>
      <Header siteTitle={data.site.siteMetadata.title} />
    </Headroom>
  )
}
```

Comment: It makes a lot of sense. Thank you very much for your answer. However, it's returning one error:  _TypeError: heroDims is undefined_. I've done as you suggested, using forwaredRef in hero.js, ending with this `const Hero = React.forwardRef(({ siteTitle }, ref ) => (
  <StyledBackgroundSection className={'w-full h-screen'} >
    <div class={'w-full h-full flex items-center'} ref={ref}>`, then added this same hook you gave within hooks/useElementsDimensions and added the proper code into Layout.js. Gonna recheck my code now to see if i didn't mistyped something

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry it'll come back `undefined` until the ref is set. I'll typically create a fallback. I'll update the code now.

Comment: It did work! Thanks! I see we need to set a origin point with top and height values. That´s clever! Shall I make and anwser with your question?

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed the check button to mark your as the right one.